# Custom class extends ImageButton, not work onClick

Tags: android, class

I want to make a custom class based on ImageButton. Also, determine the action when click the button. But I regret to say the method onClick does not work in the class. What could be the problem?

```
public class CircleButton extends ImageButton implements View.OnClickListener{
private boolean checked;

public CircleButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public CircleButton(Context context, AttributeSet set) {
    super(context, set);
    init(context);
}

public CircleButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //setChecked(!isChecked());
    Log.d("CircleButton", "setBackground()");
    setBackground();
}

private void init (Context context) {
    setOnClickListener(this);
}

public boolean isChecked() {
    return checked;
}

public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    this.checked = checked;
    setBackground();
}

private void setBackground() {
    setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_about);
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


}
```

}

Comment: The View seems to be OK. Could you post the xml?

Comment: In Activity works event in onClick method, but in this class do not.
`<com.softinlife.templatestyles.Views.Button.CircleButton
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/circlebtn"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_circle_background" />`